# Upgrading 2.7 to 2.7.1 with MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager, upgrade, ee2-upgrades, 2.7.0, 2.7.1

I have EE 2.7 running with MSM 2.16 and want to upgrade to EE 2.7.1 to fix some bugs

Outside of restoring the three files that come with MSM is there anything else that has to be done differently because of MSM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is all you have to do.

Comment: Thank you -- I don't this is covered in the MSM docs.